# SimpleAdapter - вместо последнего айтема отображается первый

Tags: android, adapter

Народ, я уже не могу продвигаться дальше, мозги невыносимо болят. Помогите, ничего не получается у меня.
Вообшем, мне нужен свой адаптер для того, чтобы проверять данные на `null` и в случае совпадения скрывать `TextView`. А у меня пока даже не получается осуществить саму работу адаптера. Вот что я делаю:

**Разметка**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/name_item"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#F95D1C"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/vdohnovenie"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#FFA000"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/popular"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#F0FF00"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/money"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/guitar"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#00AAFF"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/vokal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#5F7FD0"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/harizma"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#AE51C7"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/style"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Подготовка данных и отправка в адаптер**

```
lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1)
String[] summary_lv2 = {"Слушать радио", "Выпить пива", "Общаться с крутыми музыкантами", "Выпить пива с музыкантами", "Слушать комп", "Слушать винил",  "Концерт местной группы", "Концерт отечественной группы", "Концерт зарубежной группы"};
String[] secondary_vdxnvn_lv2 = {"5", "15", "10", "15", "10", "15", "30", "50", "80"};
String[] secondary_popular_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_money_lv2 = {"", "-60", "", "-120", "", "", "-400", "-600", "-1000"};
String[] secondary_guitar_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_vokal_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_harizma_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1"};
String[] secondary_style_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1"};
String[] from = {"name_item", "vdoxnovenie", "popular", "money", "guitar", "vokal", "harizma", "style"};
int[] to = {R.id.name_item, R.id.vdohnovenie, R.id.popular, R.id.money, R.id.guitar, R.id.vokal, R.id.harizma, R.id.style};
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> hashmap;
for(int i = 0; i < summary_lv2.length; i++){
hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashmap.put("name_item", "" + summary_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("vdoxnovenie", "+" + secondary_vdxnvn_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("popular", "" + secondary_popular_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("money", "" + secondary_money_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("guitar", "" + secondary_guitar_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("vokal", "" + secondary_vokal_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("harizma", "" + secondary_harizma_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("style", "" + secondary_style_lv2[i]);
arrayList.add(hashmap);
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayList, R.layout.item, from, to);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Адаптер**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adapterList;
    Context adapterContext;
    int adapterLayout;
    String[] adapterFrom;
    int[] adapterTo;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;       
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int layout, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, layout, from, to);
        adapterContext = context;
        adapterList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) data;
        adapterLayout = layout;
        adapterFrom = from;
        adapterTo = to;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater)adapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return adapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return adapterList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null) {
            v =  lInflater.inflate (R.layout.item, null);
 ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name_item)).setText(adapterList.get(position).get("name_item"));
        }
        else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Пока что, тестирую отображение `name_item`. Текст в последнем айтеме содержит текст из первого айтема. Почему?

Comment: вам в `getView` надо устанавливать значения `TextView` всегда, а не только у новых view.

Comment: Тебе необходимо следить за памятью - поковыряйся в кишках и обнаружишь, что старые итемы не удаляются и вставляются вместо тех, что должны быть.
Ответ на твой вопрос - вручную следи за тем, что показываешь

Comment: @zRrr, спасибо) опубликуйте как ответ, поставлю галку